# Which callback does ActiveRecord use to record timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm just wondering here whether any of you guys know when ActiveRecord use it's "magic" to record the timestamp (e.g. created_at, updated_at).

What i mean when is, at which callback ? (if AR use callback at all).

I'm asking this because I want to create an auto-updating column (that record sequential number for each object) and I want to replicate AR way to do this as much as possible.

EDITED:
It seems that AR does it between after_validation and before_create/before_update. You can do some tests for this by creating a presence validation for created_at column and inserting new record with blank created_at, it would return an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where AR does it, but the proper place for what you describe sounds like `before_create`

Comment: hmm.. i've tried something by placing a presence validations for "created_at" and it returns error. it seems that AR does it around after_validation and before_create/before_update.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3.2.12, this code is located in `lib/active_record/timestamp.rb`.

As you mention in your question and DGM suggests, Rails will update the timestamps when creating or updating, so sticking your code in `before_create` and `before_update` should work.

You may also want to take a look at [the ActiveRecord `counter_cache` functionality](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/increment_counter).  ActiveRecord supports creation of a column that can automatically be incremented/decremented.  Additionally, you can perform [more complicated logic](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters).